# How to make SQL search query for firstname, lastname

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have for example an model:

```
User :firstname   :lastname
     joseph       smith
     anna         bauer
     ...          ...
```

And an input field where you can search for an **user**. The different search queries could be:

```
  searchquery1:  smith joseph
  searchquery2:  joseph smith
  searchquery3:  joseph
  searchquery4:  smith
```

Which search query in SQL would be the best? Actually I could imagine this search query:

```
  where 'firstname OR lastname  LIKE ?', "%#{search}"
```

**First try:**

```
def self.search(search)
 if search
   select('CONCAT(vorname, " ", nachname) as full_name, *')
   where ['vorname LIKE :s OR nachname  LIKE :s OR full_name LIKE :s', :s => "%#{search}"]
 else
  scoped
 end
end
```

error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: full_name`

**Second try:**

```
def self.search(search)
 if search
  a = search.split
   where('firstname OR lastname  LIKE ?', a[1])
   where('firstname OR lastname  LIKE ?', a[2]) unless a[2].nil?
  else
  scoped
 end
end
```

Problem: Finds nothing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to search it on both first name and last name like this

```
select('(firstname || " " || lastname) as \'full_name\', *')
where ['firstname LIKE :s OR lastname  LIKE :s OR full_name LIKE :s', :s => "%#{search}"]
```

but if the data is too big. You can use the full text search engines like Solr or thinkin sphinx

Comment: I updated my question, your advice is first try but how you can see i get an error

Comment: Sorry im beginner i didnt know there is an difference! I think there is an typo error in your anwer one ' is missing!

Comment: Yes of course but could you first correct your answer? I corrected it myself but that didnt worked

Comment: Sorry but i get the error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: full_name: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "patients"  WHERE

Comment: do you know the solution if I have to use joins? Currently I have self.joins(:address).where('customers.email LIKE :query_string OR addresses.first_name LIKE :query_string OR addresses.last_name LIKE :query_string', {query_string: "%#{query}%"}) . How can I incorporate the full_name? How my select statement should be?

Answer (score 0):

To make search on firstname, lastname and fullname;

Member.where ['first_name LIKE :s OR last_name  LIKE :s OR CONCAT(first_name,last_name) LIKE :s', :s => "#{search.delete(' ')}"]

It works!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you want search on lastname and firstname you must do :

```
User.where('firstname or lastname like ?', params[:search])
```

An another solution : https://github.com/ernie/squeel, https://github.com/ernie/squeel#predicates

Answer (score -1):

```
User.where("(first_name || ' ' || last_name) like :q", :q => params[:search])
```

Comment: This does not work. See: `searchquery1:  smith joseph`, `searchquery2:  joseph smith`. Your answer will not work for a query where the last name precedes the first name.